# Using Twitter Bootstrap to style an email contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am still very new to programming and trying to learn with rails. I have copied and pasted the email form from http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/ and I am now trying to apply twitter bootstrap styling to the form below. I have tried several different ways with no luck but I guess I lack understanding of what and why the fieldset tag exist and how to apply the various css classes to what I think are helpers. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great (still very new to programming, design, and rails so if one could confirm that I am looking at helpers here that would be a bonus).

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
<fieldset class="fields">
 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :subject %>
  <%= form.text_field :subject %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :venue %>
  <%= form.text_field :venue %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :date %>
  <%= form.text_field :date %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :time %>
  <%= form.text_field :time %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :body %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
 </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="actions">
  <%= form.submit "Send" %>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be:

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |form| %>
<fieldset>
 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :name, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :email, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :subject, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_field :subject %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :venue, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_field :venue %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :date, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_field :date %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :time, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_field :time %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <%= form.label :body, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </div>
 </div>

</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

It's going to be a headache adding this styles in a large Rails application with more than one form. So I recommend you to use [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem that come with twitter bootstrap generator (read the installation guide).

With this gem your form will be bootstrap ready as simple as this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, :url => contact_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.input :email %>
  <%= form.input :subject %>
  <%= form.input :venue %>
  <%= form.input :date %>
  <%= form.input :time %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am typing this from my phone so I can't go into too much detail. The fieldset tag in HTML is for grouping related form fields. It doesn't do much. You could probably remove it of you wanted to.

Twitter bootstrap is relatively strict about the way your HTML is organized and which classes are applied. You will be better off by copying some example form HTML from the Twitter bootstrap docs and replacing the form fields with the Rails code to generate them.